# Crash without error upon iterating through NSFetchRequest results

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I'm using an `NSFetchRequest` to get all core data entities in a context, and I'm moving them to another context.

This works fine doing it with just 1 entity. I can iterate through results very quickly. The entity has a relationship with another entity however, so I need to run a second `NSFetchRequest` to get the entities which are joined by this relationship. It's the second `NSFetchRequest` which is causing the crash. The crash just makes the app quit to the homescreen and no errors appear in the xcode log. I've commented out my code to figure out that this is the problem, and have got it down to this:

```
    NSError *error;
    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSManagedObjectContext *oldContext = [self version1ManagedObjectContext];
    TICDSSynchronizedManagedObjectContext *newContext = [self version1_1ManagedObjectContext];


    NSFetchRequest *oldFetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *oldEntryEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entry"
                                                      inManagedObjectContext:oldContext];
    [oldFetchRequest setEntity:oldEntryEntity];
    [oldFetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:10];
    NSArray *entrys = [oldContext executeFetchRequest:oldFetchRequest error:&error];


    int totalEntries = [oldContext countForFetchRequest:oldFetchRequest error:nil];

    NSLog(@"total entries: %i", totalEntries);


    int i = 0;

    while (i < totalEntries) {
        @autoreleasepool {

            Entry *entry = [entrys objectAtIndex:i];

            Entry *newEntry = [NSEntityDescription
                               insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entry"
                               inManagedObjectContext:newContext];

            //Taking out this fetch request means it functions fine
            NSFetchRequest *mediaRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

            NSEntityDescription *mediaEntity = [NSEntityDescription
                                                entityForName:@"Media"
                                                inManagedObjectContext:oldContext];

            [mediaRequest setEntity:mediaEntity];

            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                                      @"(entry == %@)", entry];
            [mediaRequest setPredicate:predicate];

            NSArray *mediaItems = [oldContext executeFetchRequest:mediaRequest error:&error];

            int totalMediaItems = [oldContext countForFetchRequest:mediaRequest error:nil];

            NSLog(@"total media items: %i", totalMediaItems);


            int i2 = 0;

            while (i2 < totalMediaItems) {
                @autoreleasepool {


                    Media *newMedia = [NSEntityDescription
                                       insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Media"
                                       inManagedObjectContext:newContext];

                    i2++;

                }
            }

            [newContext save:&error];

            i++;
        }
    }
```

Any ideas why this might be crashing my app?

In answer to any questions about what I'm trying to do - I'm trying to migrate data between 2 versions. Standard data migration, using mapping, does not work with large data, such as `NSData`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there are few more code lines that you don't expose here. The ones where you copy the data from the old entities to the new ones...
Maybe the problem is there.

Anyway, I would add NSLog between every 2 lines of code and see which is the last one that is printed...
I think that something is autoreleased in the inner loop and you try to use it in the next iteration.

Comment: Nope, i commented out all of those lines for the sake of testing. Eveything above is literally all there is.

Comment: Strangely enough, when I commented out everything relating to the Entry entity, it crashed on it's first time of running, on the `executeFetchRequest` line.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you edit the scheme that you are using to build and enable everything for the diagnostics tab.  This will probably spit out whatever might be causing the issue.

Comment: I just enabled everything, and unfortunately the last message is a standard core data one: `CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZISINPHOTOLIBRARY, t0.ZLARGETHUMBNAIL, t0.ZORIGINALIMAGE, t0.ZENTRY, t0.Z_FOK_ENTRY FROM ZMEDIA t0 WHERE  t0.ZENTRY IN  (?)`